# Netzke extending actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, netzke

I want to extend the behavior of **apply action** in **netzke grid**. While applying changes in the grid I want to display a confirmation message (same as in delete action).
What I have done is given below.

```
js_configure do |c|
c.on_apply = <<-JS
  function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(this.i18n.confirmation,
      this.i18n.areYouSure, function(btn) {
      if (btn == 'yes') {
        this.getStore().sync();
      }
    }, this);
  }
JS
```

Now the popup is displayed but data is not saving to DB. Also the loading effect while saving is gone. Can anybody help?
Thanks.

Comment: This code works fine for me. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The value is not saving to DB.
When I hit the refresh button the value get reverted.
Also while applying changes the loader is missing.

Comment: Have you really looked for errors in the browser console?

Comment: Please give me one more day. Let me trouble shoot this once again. If nothing happens I will post the full component code here. Thanks for your valuable support.

Comment: Yes, I checked for errors. But no errors is displayed. Let me send the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my update on your previous post. I changed the approach. Instead of completely bypassing the onApply action, I just added a bit of code that asks the question and then calls the original onApply. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Please give me at least 1 day to check this as I am unable to access my application right now. If this works then surely I will let you know.

Comment: Great work! This works pretty well for me. Thanks for the great support.